# Is there any way to get the previous value at the time of calculation in Python Polars?

Tags: python-polars

Is there any way to get the previous value at the time of calculation in Python Polars?

| s | c |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 |

result_col = (s[i] * c[i]) + ((1 - s[i]) * **result_col[i-1]**)

I'm trying to speed up the formula.
When I try to do it with Python, it takes a long time with big data.
The adjust=false property in the ewm_mean function in Polars uses this kind of calculation.
Is there any way to do this with Polars?
If not, can there be an improvement for this kind of calculations?
I have seen a few questions about this kind of formula before, but they are not fully solved. I think others will also need the previous value calculated at the time of calculation in such formulas. Thanks.

[Previously asked - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76886343/custom-cumulative-expression-on-rows-in-polars)

[Previously asked - 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77196845/how-to-compute-a-new-polars-column-based-on-its-previous-value)

Comment: I think the general recommendation is to use numba instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77659748/ - https://stackoverflow.com/a/78058031/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I wrote in the topic, Polars' ewm_mean function uses the previous value at the time of calculation when the adjust value is given false. And I am sure that others will need this kind of calculations like me. If this calculation cannot be done, I think it was a title created more for polars developers to consider.

Comment: Yeah, I think the issue is that a "dynamic" solution cannot be provided that is efficient. `ewm_mean` is hardcoded at the Rust level. I believe you are essentially asking for a vertical fold: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12165 - numba gets recommended because it's simpler to use than writing a Rust plugin.